# Style not working on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I'm doing a project on AndroidStudio and I changed the style so I have my actionbar with a custom color and icon. On AndroidStudio's preview all looks good and there aren't any errors, but when I run the app on the Genymotion emulator, on the first screen, the actionbar is in the default color of Theme.Holo.Light (light grey) and the custom icon isn't showing. On another screen, there isn't an actionbar at all.

Here is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#73AEC0</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/money_logo</item>
</style>
```

and in the AndroidManifest there is this:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="MyTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red_color</item>
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/money_logo</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/red_color</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/money_logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>
</style>
```

In values/color.xml use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="red_color">#ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

Name your manifest to

```
 android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

Comment: I had that in the first place, but I changed it, because then it gives me this error : You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: For the parent of your AppTheme, change the Theme.Holo.Light to an AppCompat theme like Theme.AppCompat.Light. You need to make them all appcompat

Comment: Still not working. Now, on the first screen, the actionbar doesn't have text either.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I provided a copy/paste solution

Comment: And please make sure your icon is small. If it's too big, the title won't be displayed